# Get all the values of single key from the list map java8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap

I have the list as follows:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> mapList=new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,Object> mapObject=new HashMap<String,Object>();
mapObject.put("No",1);
mapObject.put("Name","test");
mapList.add(mapObject);
Map<String,Object> mapObject1=new HashMap<String,Object>();
mapObject1.put("No",2);
mapObject1.put("Name","test");
mapList.add(mapObject1);

and so on...
```

Now I want to get all the values of the key "No" as a string seperated by comma as follows:

```
String noList="1,2,3"
```

Can anyone please suggest me what may best way to do it. I know we can do it by looping but instead of looping is any other ways to do it.

Comment: Even though this is easily achievable, I will strongly recommend consider revising your data structure to a flatter map or possibly map of maps, keyed by the `No`.

Comment: Try this one `mapList.stream().map(map -> map
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(m -> m.getKey().equals("No"))
                .map(m -> m.getValue().toString())
                .findFirst().get())
              .collect(Collectors.joining(","))`

Answer (score 3):

Explanations inline!

```
mapList.stream()                       // stream over the list
    .map(m -> m.get("No"))             // try to get the key "No"
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)          // filter any null values in case it wasn't present
    .map(Object::toString)             // call toString for each object
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")); // join the values
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply map the list:

```
String list = mapList.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.containsKey("No")) // get only the maps that has the key
    .map(x -> x.get("No").toString()) // every map will be transformed like this
   .collect(Collectors.joining(",")); // joins all the elements with ","
System.out.println(list);
```

The use of `HashMap<String, Object>` suggests that it might be better to create a new class for this data. Have you considered this possibility before?

Comment: You might want to filter first, in case a map doesn't contain a "No" entry (which would cause an NPE in your code). `...stream().filter(m -> m.containsKey("No"))...`

Comment: This is a beautiful solution. I need to learn this stream thing D:

Comment: Actually, I like the short internal loop version a lot as well now, consider my answer.

Comment: I prefer `.map(x -> x.get("No")).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(Object::toString)` instead of performing two map lookups.

Comment: Ok, if you prefer unique alternatives, Java 9: `String list = mapList.stream() .flatMap(x -> Optional.ofNullable(x.get("No")).stream()) .map(Object::toString) .collect(Collectors.joining(","));`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop like this:

```
List<String> noList = new ArrayList<>(mapList.size());
for (Map<String,Object> m : mapList) {
    Optional.ofNullable(m.get("No")) // get value mapped to "No" or empty Optional
        .map(Object::toString)
        .ifPresent(noList::add); // if not empty, add to list
}
System.out.println(String.join(",", noList));
```

or internally (the officially preferred version IIRC):

```
List<String> noList = new ArrayList<>(mapList.size());
mapList.forEach(m -> 
    Optional.ofNullable(m.get("No")).map(Object::toString).ifPresent(noList::add));
System.out.println(String.join(",", noList));
```

Now that I think of it, it's shorter than the `Stream` version.

Comment: @Holger could have Seiten, so much that I didn't bother looking it up. Luckily it's only a line more, edited :)

Answer (score 0):

Answered a pretty similar question 30 minutes ago.

You are using repeated keys. This makes it look like you don't need maps, but a class with the attributes "No", "Name", etc. If you've this class you can just iterate your instances on the list and concatenating to a String.

If no matter what you want to have your maps, simply get the values of the "No" key, but note that this is a wrong practise and you should be probably using a class instead of maps:

```
String res = "";

for(int i = 0; i < mapList.size(); i++) {
    Map<String,Object> map = mapList.get(i);
    res.concat(map.get("No"));
    if(i != mapList.size() - 1)
        res.concat(",");
}
```

PS: If you are going with the bad solution practise, use the stream alternatives in the other answers if your knowledge of stream is enough to understand them.

Comment: At the very least, use a `StringBuilder` for consecutive `append`s. Also, you might want to use `for (Map<String,Object> m : mapList)...`. Also, you're missing brackets around the `map.get`.

Comment: StringBuilder is unncesary in terms of efficency since a looong time ago. Thanks for pointing out the missing brackets.

Comment: No, you're thinking of `StringBuffer`. You can do without a `StringBuilder` if you do concatenation in a single line (eg `"a" + v + "b" + w + "c"`) because that internally uses a `StringBuilder`; a for loop like yours is a different thing.

Comment: Oh wow. Didn't know that!! Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: Since Java strings are immutable, `String.concat` creates and returns a new `String` instance. You are not assigning the result of `concat` anywhere, so it gets lost and at the end of your loop, `res` is still pointing to the empty string. That’s the fundamental difference to using a `StringBuilder`, whose `append` methods will modify the builder’s contents. Further, `concat` requires its argument to be a `String` but you are trying to pass an `Object` to it (in the first use). You would get the assignment and conversion for free if you just used `res += map.get("No");`.